# add cloud_watch_logs_role_arn to aws_cloudtrail resource terraform

Tags: terraform

Hi I am following the guide for https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/compliance/AWS_CIS_Foundations_Benchmark.pdf. I would like to complete the infrastructure changes for section 3. To start this process I need to create an `aws_cloudtrail` resource with SSE-KMS encryption enabled. I'm currently reviewing the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudtrail) for this resource. How do I automate the process of specifying the role for the CloudWatch Logs endpoint to assume to write to a user’s log group?

```
resource aws_cloudtrail "cisbenchmark" {
  name                          = "cis-benchmark"
  enable_logging                = true
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.cisbenchmark.bucket
  enable_log_file_validation    = true
  is_multi_region_trail         = true
  include_global_service_events = true
  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn     = ????
  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cisbenchmark.arn
  kms_key_id                    = var.kms_key_arn
  is_organization_trail         = true

}
```

I've added `????` to specify where I'm missing the attribute.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for the answer:

```
resource aws_cloudtrail "cisbenchmark" {
  name                          = "cis-benchmark"
  enable_logging                = true
  s3_bucket_name                = aws_s3_bucket.cisbenchmark.bucket
  enable_log_file_validation    = true
  is_multi_region_trail         = true
  include_global_service_events = true
  cloud_watch_logs_role_arn     = aws_iam_role.cloud_trail.arn
  cloud_watch_logs_group_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cisbenchmark.arn
  kms_key_id                    = var.kms_key_arn
  is_organization_trail         = true
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloud_trail" {
  name = "cloudTrail-cloudWatch-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "aws_iam_role_policy_cloudTrail_cloudWatch" {
  name = "cloudTrail-cloudWatch-policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.cloud_trail.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailCreateLogStream2014110",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cisbenchmark.arn}:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailPutLogEvents20141101",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.cisbenchmark.arn}:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```